# Broken Product Links

Tags: magento-1.9, url-rewrite, ce-1.9.2.2

After doing some system upgrades, many product links on my site are broken.

The links that DON'T work, look like this:
http://merkazhasofrim.com/sofrus/quills/pre-shaped-plastic-quill-tips.html

The links that DO work, look like this:
http://merkazhasofrim.com/sofrus/powders-whiteners/white-art-pastel-chalk.html#.VrOf4vGMlvU

For some reason, the system is adding characters to the original URL rewrite and only then does the link work.

I already flushed the table called core_url_rewrite and reindexed Category URL Rewrites in the admin, but it doesn't seem to help.

I am running Magento V 1.9.2.2
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Just letting everyone know what helped.
I was told that "Add This" often creates these types of link problems.
I removed it and problem solved.